# Passing data from a Datagrid to Report Viewer

Tags: vb.net

I'm relatively new to form programming in Visual Basic and need some help.

I've successful got what I want from my database into a datagrid but need this in a report viewer.

```
    dgvReport.DataSource = dsReport

    Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable("GenerateReport")
    Dim ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("GenerateReport", ds)

    rvReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    rvReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSource)
    rvReport.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Test.Report1.rdlc"
    rvReport.RefreshReport()
```

Where 'dsReport' is the name of the dataset I'm using.
'Generate Report' is the table name within the dataset.
"Test.report1.rdlc" is the path of the report file.

I've searched and found this code, but the error I get says that the the program cannot find the file. I was unaware that there's a file saved which you then copy the data from into the report viewer.

I don't know if this is right, what I'm doing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Here are the docs, they might help some: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-webforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really help me a great deal.

Comment: You said you 'searched and found this code' -- did you just copy/paste it? If so, the documentation will be helpful.  Good luck.